# Nesting two divs in a "header" div breaks the design

Tags: css, html

I have a header that should always be displayed on top of the page about 20px from the top.
Right now it is defined with two divs and working the way it's supposed to.

http://jsfiddle.net/nBgj4/

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
body {
    height: 100%;
    margin-left: 20px;
    margin-top:0px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;

}
.subheader-left {
    position: absolute;
    top: 20px;
    font-family: serif;
    font-size: 20px;
    text-align: left;
}
.subheader-right{
position: absolute;
font-family: sans-serif;
font-size: 12px;
top: 20px;
right: 20px;}
</style>

<title>XYZ</title>

</head>
<body>
    <div class="subheader-left">XYZ<br /></div>
    <div class="subheader-right">LOREM</div>
</body>
</html>
```

As soon as I try to encapsulate the two DIV tags with a "header" DIV tag and assign it the elements that both encapsulated divs have in common (top: 20px) it breaks the design.

I always assumed that nested divs inherit from their parent divs and want to understand why this is not working in this case. I assum it is because of the "position: absolute" tag, but "position: relative" breaks the design.

thanks

http://jsbin.com/emulel/1/edit

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
body {
    height: 100%;
    margin-left: 20px;
    margin-top:0px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;

}
.header {top:20px;}
.subheader-left {
    position: relative;
    font-family: serif;
    font-size: 20px;
    text-align: left;
}
.subheader-right{
position: relative;
font-family: sans-serif;
font-size: 12px;
right: 20px;}
</style>

<title>XYZ</title>

</head>
<body>
<div class="header">
    <div class="subheader-left">XYZ<br /></div>
    <div class="subheader-right">LOREM</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: post on jsFiddle.net please. Makes it much easier and painless for all of us

Comment: also..`position:absolute` causes the element to have distance properties relative to the root <html> element meaning `top:20px` will always be 20px from the top of the screen regardless of where it is nested

Comment: @MattHintzke Actually `top: 20px` will do nothing here, 'couse `.header` have default position to `static`

Comment: @Roland `position: relative` mean that you move `element` 20px right from current position, `position: absolute` will move `element` 20px right from first relative parent element, default it will be `body`

Comment: @MattHintzke thanks, but doesn't static mean it's just in the normal flow? shouldn't it then be moved 20px down as well from its parent (the body tag?).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you mix a few things up:

header has no position assigned, so top: 20px; is useless. If you position elements, absolute will always positioned against a relative positioned element.

You should go for float:

keep your html like it is and add this CSS:

```
.header {
  overflow: hidden;/* to contain the floated elements */
}
.subheader-left {
  float: left;
}.subheader-right {
  float: left;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should see you on the right path:

http://fiddle.jshell.net/3gZNM/3/

No need for absolute positioning.

Answer (score 0):

You need

```
.subheader-left {
float:left;
}
.subheader-right{
float:right;
}
```

That's because in the first example, the divs have `position:absolute`, so their width is minimal.

But on the second one they have `position:relative` and its `display` is `block`, so they expand and their width is maximal. Then the second div goes to the second line.

But if you add floating, their width will be minimal and they will stay at the same line. Moreover, the second div will go to the right.

But then remember to change header's `overflow` into `hidden`, `auto` or `scroll`, or add `<div style="clear:both"></div>` at the end of the header.